# Не получается послать на сервер Node данные

Tags: javascript, node.js

Нужно послать не сервер  NodeJs пост запрос с данными id, name, zip.

Получаю данные с апи и с помощью reduce редактирую в нужный мне формат, вторая функция должна посылать данные на сервер но что то не получается.

Если console.log делаю то получаю в консоли ответ {id:11} хотя такого id даже нет.

Прошу помощи что не так делаю ?

```
const url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users'
async function getResponse(url) {
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const result = await response.json();
    return await result.reduce((acc, item) => {
        const {id, name, address: {zipcode}} = item;
        acc.push({id, name, zipcode})
        return acc
    }, []);
}

async function sendRequest(method, url , body = null) {
    const headers = {
        'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'
    }
    return fetch(url, {
        method: method,
        body: JSON.stringify(body),
        headers: headers
    }).then(response => {
        if (response.ok) {
            return response.json();
        }
        return response.json()
            .then(err => {
                const e = new Error("Error");
            e.data = err
            throw e
        })
    })
}

getResponse(url).then(data => console.log(data));

sendRequest('POST', url, getResponse(url))
.then(data => console.log(data))
.catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Comment: Вам надо отдебажить код. Посмотреть, что на каждом этапе отправляется, приходит, посмотреть вкладку network панели разработчика. Возможно где то кривые данные отправляются или считаются.